# Problems with plotting a function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, maple

I can't find out why maple won't plot a type of function the way it's supposed to be.
[Here are the functions I need to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdsyk.png)

I'm considering B=24, h=0, t=10.2 and epsilon as the only variable.

The result I'm getting from mapple is [this one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6msh.png).
But I'm suppose to get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fODHC.png).
The problematics ones are those in the middle, they correspond to E3 and E4.

Does anyone has any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an example where the new (Maple 2022) adaptive plotting scheme goes awry.

It can be remedied here by forcing the previous default scheme. Using Robert's formulation of the equations:

```
B:= 24: h:= 0: t:= 10.2: 
E1:= sqrt(B^2 + epsilon^2 + h^2 + 4*t^2 
   + 2*sqrt(epsilon^2 * B^2 + 4*B^2 * t^2 + 
   epsilon^2*h^2))/2;
E2:= -E1;
E3:= sqrt(B^2 + epsilon^2 + h^2 + 4*t^2 
   - 2*sqrt(epsilon^2 * B^2 + 4*B^2 * t^2 + 
   epsilon^2*h^2))/2;
E4:= -E3;

plot([E1,E2,E3,E4], epsilon = -45 .. 45,
     adaptive = true);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for teaching me this option, I didn't have any idea it existed. I'll surely remember if I get any more errors like this!

Answer (score 1):

What you're "supposed to get" seems to have two curves with each label E0 to E3, solid and dotted, and no E4's.

It might help if you provided the actual Maple code you used.  But here's what I get:

```
B:= 24: h:= 0: t:= 10.2: 
E1:= sqrt(B^2 + epsilon^2 + h^2 + 4*t^2 
   + 2*sqrt(epsilon^2 * B^2 + 4*B^2 * t^2 + epsilon^2*h^2))/2;
E2:= -E1;
E3:= sqrt(B^2 + epsilon^2 + h^2 + 4*t^2 
    - 2*sqrt(epsilon^2 * B^2 + 4*B^2 * t^2 + epsilon^2*h^2))/2;
E4:= -E3;
plot([E1,E2,E3,E4], epsilon = -45 .. 45);
```

[image]

I'm guessing your problem is with how the intersections with the $x$ axis look.
This is a problem with roundoff error, I think. Note that with $h = 0$,

$$ B^2 + \epsilon^2 + 4 t^2 - 2 B \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + 4 t^2} = \left(B - \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + 4 t^2}\right)^2 $$
so your $$E3 = \left| B - \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + 4 t^2} \right|/2 $$
With that for $E3$ (and of course $E4 = -E3$), I get this:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for making you guess what my problem was, I'll try to be more specific next time. Thank you for your clarification. I think now I understand the root of the problem thanks to you. The image which has E0 to E3 correspond to E1 to E4 in the natural order as you guessed correctly, just adding 1.